# How do i output random numbers for 2 different arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

This is what i have so far but the output for both arrays is the same randomly generated numbers instead of different ones for each array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prog2_b {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Program #2b, Breanna Bergado, mascID 1885");
        System.out.println("Please enter number of elements for a 1D array:");

        int userVal = scnr.nextInt();
        //System.out.println(((Object)userVal).getClass().getName();
        double[] array = new double[userVal];
        double [] array2 = new double[userVal]; 
        double dotProd = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < userVal; i++) {
            array[i] = Math.random();
            array2[i] = Math.random();

        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            System.out.println("a"+(j+1)+"[]");
            System.out.println("----------------");
            for (int i = 0; i < userVal; i++) {
                System.out.println(array[i] + " ");


            }
            System.out.println();
        }



        for(int i = 0; i < userVal; i++) {
            dotProd = dotProd + array[i]* array2[i];

        }

        System.out.println("Dot Product is " + dotProd);

    }
}
```

Comment: You are printing `array` twice, instead of `array` and then `array2`.

Comment: so how exactly would i do that because if i print it out under the 1st array print statement it gives me 4 arrays.

Comment: That's because you've got that code in a loop (with `j`). You could remove the `j` loop and simply copy the code that was inside it, changing `array` to `array2` in the second copy..

Comment: Or you could investigate using an array *of arrays*: Instead of `array` and `array2`, you can use `array[0]` and `array[1]`. Then you can use the `j` loop to index the array of arrays, and `i` to index the inner array: `array[j][i]`

Answer (score 1):

You should update your printing logic to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userVal; i++) {
    System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
}

System.out.println();

for (int j = 0; j < userVal; j++) {
    System.out.println(array2[j] + " ");
}
```

Your current logic just prints the first array twice.  You could also use nested arrays as one of the comments suggested, but the above code will work with what you have so far.